# Nginx reverse proxy and missing trailing slash redirection

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy

I've a little problem with nginx, acting both as reverse proxy and proxified server.

On the front server, my configuration is:

```
server {
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://10.2.2.1:8999;
        }
}
```

And on the proxified server:

```
server {
    listen 10.2.2.1:8999;

    server_name example.com;
    autoindex on;

    location / {
        root /var/www/;
    }
}
```

Finally, on this proxified server, a directory `/var/www/test` exists with some files inside.

The problem occurs when I try to access to `http://example.com/test` (without trailing slash!): my browser is redirected to `http://example.com:8999/test/`... If I try to access to `http://example.com/test/`, no problem.

I've tried proxy_redirect statement which, from what I understand, allow the reverse proxy to rewrite `Location` header to avoid this kind of behavior, but this didn't worked for me. why?.

My second question is, why profixied nginx redirect me to this URL ? How I can prevent it to do that ?

Thanks by advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off [port_in_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#port_in_redirect) on the backend server.

Comment: Thanks,  I hadn't seen this option !
But the nginx redirection can it be disabled ?

Comment: What would you want it to do if /test is requested?  Return a 404?  It won't generate the directory index without the trailing slash.